# How do i automate the upload of files to a website

Tags: google-chrome-extension, upload

So the problem is that i have plenty of files to upload to a website as part of my work in a company.
The files come in multiple folders and in the website there's a combobox with names of the folder.
I'd like to know which solution would be suitable to automatically upload all the files in the corresponding element in the combobox. I was thinking a chrome extension or app but i can't find a way to control the name of the file that the file browser must get.
Ps: the names of the folders are the same as in the website
each folder contains 1 or more file with the same name
Thanks

Comment: It's probably best to write it in node.js, there may be existing utilities so try searching. For an extension, you'd have to enable "file access" in chrome://extensions page for your extension,  then it'll be able to read local files directly using a `file://` URL into a `blob`, then use the [FormData API](https://devdocs.io/dom/formdata) and post the files directly to the server URL using `fetch` with `POST` method. There may be examples around, keep looking.

Comment: Thanks a lot wOxxOm I will try to search